# Prolog - Can't create a useful list of related elements

Tags: list, prolog

So I have to make this little program.
The idea is that there has been several parties, in which there were people invited (we know who those people were, and who cantStand whom).The thing is that I need this to be able to tell me if a party was violent, a violent party is such, where everyone cantStand someone who is there, but I just can't seem to figure it out, I thought I just had it, when I was able to unify people who were in a party who couldn't stand someone, so if every person who's at a given party feelsAnnoyed by another Guest, then that party was a `violentParty/1`.
any help? I don't know why this doesn't give me the right output, it just says false when I consult `violentParty(Date)`.
The code:

```
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), flor).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), marina).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), pablo).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), pablo).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), leo).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), flor).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), fer).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), mati).

cantStand(leo, flor).
cantStand(pablo, fer).
cantStand(fer, leo).
cantStand(flor, fer).

violentParty(Date):-
    cameToThePartyThatDay(People,Date),
    findall(X,member(X,People),Guests),
    cantStandSomeone(Guests,ThoseWhoCantStandSomeone),
    forall(member(Guest,Guests),member(Guest,ThoseWhoCantStandSomeone)).

cantStandSomeone(Guests,List):-
    member(Guest,Guests),
    findall(FeelsAnnoyed,cantStand(FeelsAnnoyed,Guest),List).



cameToThePartyThatDay(Peoples, Date):-
    bagof(X,cameToTheParty(Date,X),Peoples).
```

Comment: `findall(X,member(X,People),Guests)` is a do-nothing clause - it just duplicates People. You could use `cameToThePartyThatDay(Guests,Date)`, or use People where you have used Guests. Doesn't solve the issue, but something I noticed at first glance.

Comment: You are right, I could definitly lose that line after I found the answer (and posted it below),  it was just a newbie mistake by confusing the unifying concepts with return-value concepts that I didn't want to make.

Comment: Annoyingly I got called into a meeting midway through posting my answer, but not worth wasting the effort of writing it, in case someone wanted a slightly different approach :)

Answer (score 1):

It was not the transformation `A -> B` (a list of B's), what I needed, because I would have to find again the relationship between A and B and that just doesn't make any sense, I needed a List of A's, by the relationship `CantStand(A,B)`, and then for every `Guest`, a `member(Guest,Guests)` should also be a `member of member(Guest,ThoseWhoCantStandSomeone)` which is beautifully done by forall.

```
comida(achura(chori, 200)). % ya sabemos que el chori no es achura
comida(achura(chinchu, 150)).
comida(ensalada(waldorf, [manzana, apio, nuez, mayo])).
comida(ensalada(mixta, [lechuga, tomate, cebolla])).
comida(morfi(vacio)).
comida(morfi(mondiola)).
comida(morfi(asado)).

leGusta(mati, chori).
leGusta(fer, mondiola).
leGusta(pablo, asado).
leGusta(mati, vacio).
leGusta(fer, vacio).
leGusta(mati, waldorf).
leGusta(flor, mixta).


leGusta(ezequiel,X):-leGusta(mati,X);leGusta(fer,X).
leGusta(marina,X):-leGusta(flor,X);comida(morfi(mondiola)).
leGusta(leo,X):-comida(X), X\=ensalada(waldorf,_).

cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), flor).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), marina).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), pablo).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), pablo).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), leo).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), flor).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), fer).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), mati).

cantStand(leo, flor).
cantStand(pablo, fer).
cantStand(fer, leo).
cantStand(flor, fer).

violentParty(Date):- 
    cameToThePartyThatDay(People,Date),
    cantStandSomeone(People,ThoseWhoCantStandSomeone),
    forall(member(Guest,People),member(Guest,ThoseWhoCantStandSomeone)).

cantStandSomeone(Guests,List):-
    findall(FeelsAnnoyed,(member(Guest,Guests),cantStand(FeelsAnnoyed,Guest)),List).



cameToThePartyThatDay(Peoples, Date):-
    bagof(X,cameToTheParty(Date,X),Peoples).
```

Answer (score 1):

So, a violent party is a party where every guest cannot stand at least one other guest. `violentParty/1` therefore finds the guests, and checks that they all can't stand someone.

How do we check that all can't stand someone? We check that, for each guest, there is someone among the guests that they can't stand.

```
violentParty(Date):-
    cameToThePartyThatDay(Guests,Date),
    allCantStandSomeone(Guests).

allCantStandSomeone(Guests) :-
    forall(member(Guest,Guests),cantStandSomeone(Guest,Guests)).

cantStandSomeone(Guest,Guests) :-
    cantStand(Guest,X),
    member(X,Guests).
```

All of which would be very useful if OP had not already solved their own problem...

Comment: Thanks. It was useful to me, gave me another way to solve it without necessary using another list.

Comment: @newbie Glad I could help!